# Theano-based libraries for RNN-based speech recognition

Tags: library, speech-recognition, neural-network

I am trying to do speech recognition using RNN. It would be really helpful if I could get some suggestions on best Theano-based libraries that I can use for RNN-based speech recognition. (I am hoping to use CTC Connectionist Temporal Classification as well.)

I heard about Keras. But I would like to know whether it would be a good selection to use it before I jump into it.

Comment: In Torch: https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no plain Theano setups just because application of RNN to speech is not trivial, you need to have a good estimation before training to make the whole system converge.

CTC implementation for speech is usually based on [Kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org) speech recognition toolkit which is used to setup the whole thing with speech specifics. You can find details here:

Theano-based extension:

https://github.com/yajiemiao/pdnn

Eesen - end-to-end recognition with CTC:

https://github.com/srvk/eesen

Another implementation from Stanford:

https://github.com/amaas/stanford-ctc