# Tensorflow-compatible Python library that provides second-order derivative for CTC loss function

Tags: library, python, machine-learning

I need a TensorFlow-compatible Python library that provides a second-order derivative for Machine Learning CTC (Connectionist Temporal Classification) loss function.

Namely, a library that provides an implementation of the `ctc_loss` function in Python API such that, in contrast to
[`tf.nn.ctc_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss),
the second gradient must be calculable analytically with reasonable performance like this:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape1: 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        loss = ctc_loss(logits=logits, ...)
    gradient = tape2.gradient(loss, sources=logits)
hessian = tape1.gradient(gradient, sources=logits)
```

This may be needed, for example, for the influence function.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), **[code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185),** etc.

Comment: Can't not agree with you @lzzy. This question is similar to 
[this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/theano-based-libraries-for-rnn-based-speech-recognition)
that is assumed to be on topic.
Besides, as mentioned
[here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/904/is-asking-for-sample-illustrative-code-on-topic)
"...they should ask for software (or by extension libraries) that solve a problem...". So extension libraries recommendation are acceptable.

Comment: Asking for **libraries** of course is on-topic here. But you asked about how to implement that functionality. Your answer proves that approach, stating "The implementation is too long to be cited here". This site is not about code nor implementation nor how-tos or code-fragments etc.pp. Added to that, answers are expected to be self-contained, not just a link to "find it there".

Comment: I rewrote the question to make it clear that you are asking for a library that offers a specific function. With that I think it is on-topic.

Comment: Thank you very much @NicolasRaoul ! The question looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

[github.com/alexeytochin/tf_seq2seq_losses](https://github.com/alexeytochin/tf_seq2seq_losses)
(disclaimer: this is my own project) is a library that offers such a function.

To use it, install `tf-seq2seq-losses` pip package

```
pip install tf-seq2seq-losses
```

Example usage:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf_seq2seq_losses import classic_ctc_loss

batch_size = 1
num_tokens = 3
logit_length = 5
logits=tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size, logit_length, num_tokens], dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape1: 
    tape1.watch([logits])
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        tape2.watch([logits])
        loss = classic_ctc_loss(
            labels=tf.constant([[1, 2, 2, 1]], dtype=tf.int32),
            logits=logits,
            label_length=tf.constant([4], dtype=tf.int32),
            logit_length=tf.constant([logit_length], dtype=tf.int32),
            blank_index=0,
        )
    gradient = tape2.gradient(loss, sources=logits)
hessian = tape1.batch_jacobian(gradient, source=logits, experimental_use_pfor=False)
```

License: Apache License, Version 2.0

Comment: The solution as written was not a good answer, in particular answers are not be place to discuss implementation, and answers should at least have usage instructions and license/price. By the way, here is the recommended workflow for people (like you and me) who write software for their own needs: 1) As soon as you identify the need, post as a question 2) While waiting for answers to show up, implement the software 3) Post your new finished software as a solution. Thanks and welcome! :-)